# How to change wordpress website Page width on Mobile device?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using  [Amadeus](https://wordpress.org/themes/amadeus/) theme on my wordpress website. It is very user friendly and useful for my website. It looks well on desktop. But On Mobile device It's page width becomes very tiny. But for posts it looks good on both mobile and desktop.
I want to increase page width(not post width) of my website on mobile device. how can I do that ?

Here is the example of a page - [page example](http://www.gkpad.com/about)
& Here is the example of a post - [post example](https://www.gkpad.com/2018/02/polytechnic-ki-taiyari-kaise-kare/)

Comment: .page .hentry { padding: 45px; ) is likely causing the issue. You should redefine the left and right padding. Make it zero using a media query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the page width on some devices of just by screen resizing you can put nodes of an elements that you want to resize in a special control css method `@media`. For example:

`@media screen and (min-width:350px) and (max-width:750px) { 
  .body { 
    width: 150%
  }}`

...and then put this info in your page style section on in main .css file of your theme.